# How do I download "Adobe Presenter" (Flash) files to replay them on my computer? (both Windows and Mac solutions appreciated)

Tags: windows, macos, download, flash

I have tried a couple of Flash downloaders but I don't arrive at downloading "Adobe Presenter" Flash documents.

I'd like to have a particular presentation offline to show it to a group of students while not having access to the Internet.

Comment: Just as an example: here is a good example of a presentation:

[Adobe Presenter Introduction][1]


  [1]: https://admin.adobe.acrobat.com/_a227210/getstartedpresenter

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way may be to look at [Httrack](http://www.httrack.com) which can allow you to download entire websites to look at offline.

Other than that, I would look at the source code for .SWF files and manually take a copy, however if you are not having success with the flash downloaders, it may not help.

Lastly, it may be that the `<object>` tags within the web page contain some information needed in order to run the flash files for example, you may have downloaded a player but no content. You may want to double check the source code of the page and download any hidden/extra files and copy and paste the entire sections to an HTML page and change the links from http://site.com/bla.swf to file:///c:\whatever\bla.swf etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, I'll go ahead and try it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it over the (mac/unix) terminal (through wget), [DeepVacuum](http://www.hexcat.com/deepvacuum), that is essentially tweaking terminal inputs and SiteSucker all to no avail.

There is the added issue of the file in question sitting behind a Shibboleth university wall of authentication which probably makes getting the file no less complicated. Mhm.